# Receiving data from a Socket with an unknown length

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, win-universal-app

I'm setting up a client-server network using the new **Windows Universal** app architecture with **Windows 10**. The aim is to have a device that will act as a **server**, and other devices can connect and send data to the server. I'm aiming to do this over **LAN**, for now at least. Let's look at some code.

The structure I have come up with is a couple of classes, `Server`, and `Client`. A server has multiple clients will listen for data sent from the client, here is the `Client`.

*Note: I'll provide the full code so it'll make it easier for you guys to debug.*

```
public class Client
{
    public StreamSocket Socket { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsConnected { get; internal set; }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(string ip, string port = "80")
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a socket and connect to the IP address.
            Socket = new StreamSocket();

            await Socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(ip), port);

            IsConnected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            IsConnected = false;

            throw;
        }
    }

    public async void SendDataAsync(string data)
    {
        //If we're not connected, then bugger this.
        if (!IsConnected)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The client is not connected to the server, connect first, then try again.");

        //Send the data.
        DataWriter stream = new DataWriter(Socket.OutputStream);

        //Write and commit the data to the server.
        stream.WriteString(data);
        await stream.StoreAsync();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            //TODO: Disconnect safely (Still working this one out)

            //Dispose of the socket.
            Socket.Dispose();
            Socket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The bit we're interested in is the `SendDataAsync` method, this is where we're sending data to the server. Here is the `Server`.

```
public class Server
{
    public List<Client> Clients { get; private set; } = new List<Client>();

    public StreamSocketListener Listener { get; private set; }
    public string Port { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the local IP address of the device.
    /// </summary>
    public HostName HostName
    {
        get
        {
            return NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IPInformation != null 
                                  && x.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4);
        }
    }

    public Server()
        : this("80")
    { }

    public Server(string port)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("port");

        Port = port;
    }

    public async Task Setup()
    {
        Listener = new StreamSocketListener();

        //Open a port to listen for connections   
        await Listener.BindServiceNameAsync(Port, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

        Listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;
    }

    private void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Client client = new Client()
        {
            Socket = args.Socket
        };

        //Add the client to the collection.
        Clients.Add(client);

        //Wait for some data.
        WaitForMessage(client);
    }

    private async void WaitForMessage(Client client)
    {
        //Open up a stream
        DataReader stream = new DataReader(client.Socket.InputStream);

        //Wait for 12 bytes (wtf, what if I don't know for sure how much data is arriving?)
        await stream.LoadAsync(12);

        //Get the message that was sent.
        string message = stream.ReadString(12);
    }
}
```

The bit we're interested in is the `WaitForMessage` method, this is where we're waiting for the client to send some data to us and we'll then do something useful with it.

Here is the `MainPage.xaml.cs` code that makes use of these classes:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Server _Server;
    private Client _Client;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        SetupServer();
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    private async void SetupServer()
    {
        //Create the server
        _Server = new Server();

        await _Server.Setup();
    }

    private async void ConnectToServer()
    {
        //Create a client and connect to the server.
        _Client = new Client();

        //Note, this may not be your IP address, input your local IP instead (ipconfig in command prompt)
        await _Client.ConnectAsync("192.168.1.5");

        //Send some data to the server.
        _Client.SendDataAsync("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

So, onto the actual problem. The following code is giving me trouble:

```
//Wait for 12 bytes (wtf, what if I don't know for sure how much data is arriving?)
await stream.LoadAsync(12);

//Get the message that was sent.
string message = stream.ReadString(12);
```

The issue here is that it might not always be **12 bytes** being sent to the server. It's 12 at the moment because that's what the size of *"Hello World!"* string is, otherwise, if the buffer is longer (larger than 12), it'll never *finish* receiving the data, as it's expecting a larger number of bytes.

Like I mentioned, I'm pretty new to networking but this doesn't really make any sense, here's what I'm expecting:

1. Client connects to the server.
2. Client sends some data then closes the stream.
3. The server recognizes that the data stream has been closed (maybe an event or something) and acts accordingly.

None of this nonsense with waiting for a given number of bytes.

Perhaps I'm looking at this problem totally wrong, **should I take a different approach?**

Here's an idea I've been considering:

1. The client tells the server how many bytes it'll send.
2. The server then sets up the stream and waits for those bytes.
3. Client sends the bytes.
4. ...
5. Profit!

However, the truth is, as I'm totally unfamiliar with this stuff, is there a *best practice* approach to the client-server architecture?

Comment: FWIW, your last outline there is how the data communication libraries I've written all work. There is no automatic protocol to determine how long a message is, you have to provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(...);
reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
uint bytesLoaded = await reader.LoadAsync(12);
```

Then, LoadAsync() will load something between 1 and 12 bytes. If it loads zero bytes, you can assume the stream is over.

There are other [InputStreamOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inputstreamoptions.aspx) and sometimes you can mix them.